# JMeter how to disable summariser.name=summary while running from command prompt

Tags: properties, jmeter

I am running Jmeter scripts from the command line. While running I get this summary after every request. I understood from the documentation that we need comment or set summariser.name=summary to none. I don't want to see this summary. Pl. let me know how to disable it.

00:44:10.785  summary +      6 in 00:00:32 =    0.2/s Avg:   241 Min:     2 Max:  1239 Err:     1 (16.67%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
00:44:10.785  summary =    498 in 00:39:27 =    0.2/s Avg:   126 Min:     0 Max:  2851 Err:    32 (6.43%)
00:44:42.892  summary +      7 in 00:00:31 =    0.2/s Avg:    88 Min:     0 Max:   418 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
00:44:42.892  summary =    505 in 00:39:57 =    0.2/s Avg:   126 Min:     0 Max:  2851 Err:    32 (6.34%)
00:45:14.999  summary +      6 in 00:00:31 =    0.2/s Avg:    73 Min:     2 Max:   216 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
00:45:14.999  summary =    511 in 00:40:28 =    0.2/s Avg:   125 Min:     0 Max:  2851 Err:    32 (6.26%)
00:45:41.565  summary +      6 in 00:00:31 =    0.2/s Avg:    68 Min:     2 Max:   205 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
00:45:41.565  summary =    517 in 00:40:58 =    0.2/s Avg:   125 Min:     0 Max:  2851 Err:    32 (6.19%)
00:46:13.681  summary +      6 in 00:00:31 =    0.2/s Avg:   103 Min:     2 Max:   384 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
00:46:13.681  summary =    523 in 00:41:29 =    0.2/s Avg:   124 Min:     0 Max:  2851 Err:    32 (6.12%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to see the summariser output in the console you can amend your command to

```
jmeter -Jsummariser.out=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

in order to make the change permanent - put this line: `summariser.out=false` to *user.properties* file.

If you want to turn off the summariser completely:

1. Open *jmeter.properties* file with your favourite text editor
2. Locate [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/jmeter.properties#L847)

   ```
   summariser.name=summary
   ```

   and either comment it by putting `#` character in front of it:

   ```
   #summariser.name=summary
   ```

   or just simply delete it
3. That's it, you won't see summariser output on next execution

More information:

- [Summariser - Generate Summary Results - configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#summariser)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)